# How to sort or by click check box to show only the status by pending in db

Tags: jquery, html, css, ionic-framework

I have one check box , with below one list view. when user click that check box, in list view which product have pending status, that alone have to populate in list view.

Here my check box code :

```
<div class="col col-50" style="border-right: 1px #ccc solid; padding-top: 12px;">
    <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 8px;">
    <span class="assertive" style="margin: 0px;color: #B90143;">Show pending</span>
</div>
```

Here my list view code :

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-icon-right clsOrders" ng-repeat="mydelivery in MyDeliveries | filter:search | limitTo:listlength | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse" ng-click="ShowDetails('{{ mydelivery.orderID }}')">
        <div class="row">
            // code to show the data
            <div class="col col-40 cls0Padding">
                <span class="balanced clsMakeContentRight font-color">{{ mydelivery.deliveryStatus }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This is my status that I will call in list view :

```
{{ mydelivery.deliveryStatus }}
```

Now how can I do that, when user press that check box I need to show only the status = pending products alone.

UPDATE :

MY CONTROLLER :

```
.controller('orderCtrl', function($scope, $state, $window, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading, orderfactory, $timeout){

    $scope.UserID = $window.localStorage.getItem("UserID");
    $scope.orderInfo = {SupervisorID : $scope.UserID};
    
    //get the orderid of clicked item
    $scope.ShowDetails = function(OiD){
        $scope.userorderID = OiD;
        $state.go('dashboarddetailsscreen', {Oid : $scope.userorderID});
    }
    
    //API calling to get the delivery details based on the userid
    $scope.GetDetails = function(){
        orderfactory.save($scope.orderInfo, function(response){
            if(response.status == 1){
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $scope.MyDeliveries = response.allorders;
                $window.localStorage.setItem("MyDeliverYOrders", JSON.stringify($scope.MyDeliveries));
                console.log( $scope.MyDeliveries);
            }
            else{
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "Failed",
                    content: "<center>"+response.message+"</center>"
                });
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.GetDetails();

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
        $ionicLoading.show();
        $scope.GetDetails();
    });

    $scope.newDev = function(){
        $state.go('newdelivery');
    }

    $scope.GoBacks = function()
    {
        $state.go('menu.mydashboard');
    };
    
})
```

My response data :

```
status": 1,
  "message": "Received all orders",
  "allorders": [
    {
      "orderID": "1",
      "customerName": "tenders",
      "orderStatus": "completed",
      "deliveryStatus": "delivered",
      "orderTotalAmount": 5545.45,
      "orderTaxAmount": 454.55,
      "orderDiscountAmount": 5,
      "orderPayableAmount": 6115,
      "orderAdvanceAmount": 0,
      "orderBalanceAmount": 6115,
      "orderDate": "2017-02-03 16:58:00",
      "dateAdded": "03",
      "monthAdded": "Feb",
      "timeAdded": "04:58 PM",
      "productCount": "102"
    },
    {
      "orderID": "2",
      "customerName": "najet",
      "orderStatus": "completed",
      "deliveryStatus": "delivered",
      "orderTotalAmount": 4500,
      "orderTaxAmount": 0,
      "orderDiscountAmount": 0,
      "orderPayableAmount": 4500,
      "orderAdvanceAmount": 4500,
      "orderBalanceAmount": 0,
      "orderDate": "2017-02-13 22:04:00",
      "dateAdded": "13",
      "monthAdded": "Feb",
      "timeAdded": "10:04 PM",
      "productCount": "10"
    },
```

like wise it will go on...

Comment: need to show your object values or a running fiddle will be fine

Comment: @Krishna9960  i have added my controller code

Comment: @Krishna9960  can you get it. any solution

Comment: Can you just add your code here on this mentioned link so that i can see the exact data being received and what you are repating

http://play.ionic.io/app/e2e8e54a4971

Comment: @Krishna9960  i was not able to add there. thats why i have pasted my full code in my question

Comment: Its only one screen , which will show the list of product with all details. and i will try to show in list view. Then i have one check box at top of list view. So if user press that check box which are the product having status = pending. that alone have to show in that list view

Comment: @Krishna9960  i have updated my response data too from db,

Comment: You have to keep two array of objects one which you are already rendering  and the other one you need filtered array with status pending. and toggle views on click of checkbox.


Basically show View-01 with all list which you are showing.
also have view two below hidden which you will show on-click of checkbox and hide view-01

Comment: i am new to ionic. Is there any example code that will be helpful